# Azure Key Vault Accessibility from different Azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Say if I have 2 different azure subscriptions individually and I create an azure vault and store a private key in it's HSM backed azure key vault container of the 1st subscription AND from different azure subscription I want to access the private key for signing an application..

Would that be possible?

In short, manage and store HSM backed key in one azure subscription and sign or validate an application with that private key from another azure subscription... is it possible?

Comment: Hello @raggie, I guess it would be possible if both the subscriptions are present in the same tenant , so that when you use a managed identity to access the keyvault in another subscription it can be provided keyvault RBAC roles as per the requirement. you can refer this Document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/secure-your-managed-hsm

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible when both the subscriptions are present on a Single tenant. So that you can assign required permissions on ***Management Plane*** and ***Data plane*** for the users or managed identities. As ***Managed HSM*** uses ***[`Azure AD authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/access-control#azure-active-directory-authentication)*** both the Subscriptions need to be in the same ***AzureAD*** tenant.

**Reference:**

- [Secure access to your managed HSMs Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/secure-your-managed-hsm#example)
- [Control Access to your managed HSM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/best-practices#control-access-to-your-managed-hsm)